# Правильность конструкции «другого выхода, как...»

Tags: грамотная-речь, как, смысл

[Прочитал тут](https://www.rbc.ru/society/24/11/2021/619dd3669a794777352283e5):

> Уже четвертая волна прошла и еще неизвестно, сколько волн будет впереди и, конечно, **выхода другого, как вакцинация, у нас нет.**

Автор хотел сказать: выхода другого, **кроме** вакцинации, у нас нет?

Или имел в виду: нет выхода другого, как вакцинация (такого же, как вакцинация, — и какого же, интересно знать)?

У кого какое мнение?

Comment: Это вы у автора спросите. Здесь вопросы типа "Угадайте, в каком ухе у меня звенит?" не приветствуются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что все правильно в этом предложении, потому что у союзного слова [КАК](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA) есть вот такое значение (оно просто встречается нечасто):
7. (*после отрицательных и вопросительных слов и выражений*). Употребляется для **обозначения ограничения; кроме, только**. *Кто, как не мы. Больше некому, как тебе*. [= Больше некому, кроме тебя.]

Отмечу, что предложение в вопросе приведено с ошибками. Правильная пунктуация такая (добавляем две запятые — перед каждым союзом "и"):
*Уже четвертая волна прошла, и еще неизвестно, сколько волн будет впереди, и, конечно, выхода другого, как вакцинация, у нас нет*. [= нет другого выхода, кроме вакцинации]

Пока они плыли, Давенант рассказал утреннюю историю, и, всесторонне обсудив ее, Петвек должен был признать, что **другого выхода, как** бегство, нет. [А. С. Грин. Дорога никуда (1929)]

Я не вижу **другого выхода, как** взятие Екатеринодара. [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга вторая. Восемнадцатый год (1928)]

Так что **другого выхода, как** организация тихой милой беседы с ученым или на худой конец с его единственной лаборанткой, у нас, боюсь, нет. [Зиновий Юрьев. Смертельное бессмертие // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

В Нацкорпусе: [другого выхода, как](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform)

Дополнение
Вполне возможно, что непонятка возникла из-за особого порядка слов в предложении (инверсии): дополнение (*выхода*) стоит впереди сказуемого, согласованное определение (*другого*) — после определяемого слова.
При прямом порядке слов предложение выглядело бы так:
... и, конечно, у нас нет другого выхода, как вакцинация.

Comment: После отрицательных и вопросительных слов и выражений...

Comment: Совершенно верно. Просто конструкция находится внутри.

Comment: Не стоит так говорить из-за того, что возникает двусмысленность. Всё же склоняюсь к тому, что это разговорный вариант. А к словарным примерам претензий нет.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, там "такого как". Но "такой" вполне можно опускать. "Же", что намекает на полное соответствие, добавлять нельзя, так как такого смысла изначально нет. Другой выход не должен быть таким же, он должен хоть немного отличаться (чтобы быть другим, но похожим, а не таким же).

Там может быть пропущено "кроме" ("кроме как"). Если строго, то "кроме" нельзя пропускать, потому что у "как" нет значения исключения. Но это слово может подразумеваться — разговорный вариант. Скорее всего, там это.

То есть два варианта, один из которых разговорный (не совсем правильный), но понять его можно.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен, что это грамматическая ошибка и следует писать ‟кроме вакцинации”, ведь вакцинация это не другой выход, а этот, определенный по контексту. Смысл написанного предложения следующий: у нас есть определенный выход, а другого, вроде вакцинации, нет.
Вряд ли автор это имел в виду, но просто допустил грамматическую ошибку. Местоимением ‟другой” обозначают не то, что определено по контексту.

Answer (score 0):

У кого какое мнение?   А мнение **неоднозначное.**

1. С одной стороны, я  не могу сказать, что это **грамматически неверная** конструкция. Конечно, у союза КАК нет значения **исключения**, указанного в словаре.   Раньше использовались такие варианты: ***иного  выхода, как только;  иного выбора, кроме; иного выбора, кроме как.***

Но грамматика стремится к упрощению; к тому же союз КАК – многозначный, а **изъяснительное** значение у него точно есть. И в Нацкорпусе можно найти много таких примеров, как:

Теперь у нее просто нет **другого выхода, как сказать** правду. У них нет **другого выхода, как мириться**. у нас нет **другого выхода, как принять** его.

2. Но интересно обратить внимание на такую деталь:  обычно в приведенных примерах **союз КАК относится к глаголам**, а предложений  с существительными не так уж много (другого выхода, как вакцинация, у нас нет).
3. А вот почему?  Я могу предположить следующее: в таких предложениях **сравнительное значение** союза КАК проявляется слишком явно.  А дословное прочтение конструкции , когда «выход» сравнивается с  другим существительным, представляется пользователю **некорректным**  и напрягает слух.
4. Поэтому я назвала бы это предложение **стилистически некорректным** (стилистически неточным, разговорным).  Соответственно, по возможности в таких случаях лучше  использовать глаголы, а не существительные, например:

*Уже четвертая волна прошла и еще неизвестно, сколько волн будет впереди и, конечно, **другого выхода, как вакцинировать** большую часть населения, у нас нет.*